# If insert into static array is Space-O(1), how does space complexity work?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, complexity-theory, space-complexity, amortized-analysis

Copy of static array is SO(N) (because the space required for this operation scales linearly with N)

Insert into static array is SO(1)

> 'because although it needs to COPY the first array and add the new element, after the copy it frees the space of the first array' - a quote from the source I'm learning about standard collections' TS complexity.

When we are dealing with time complexity, if the algorithm houses O(N) operation, the whole time complexity of the algorithm is AT LEAST O(N).

I struggle to understand how exactly do we measure Space complexity. I thought we look at 'the difference in memory after the completion of the run of the algorithm to determine whether it scales with N' - that would constitute insert into static array being SO(1).

But then, by that method, if I have an algorithm, that through the course of its run uses `N!` space to get a single value, and at the very end I would clean up the memory allocated for that N! items, the algorithm would be Space-O(1).

Actually, every single algorithm, that does not directly deal with entities, that remain after its run course would be O(1) (cause as we do not need the created entities after the algorithm, we can clean up the memory at the end).

Please help me understand the situation here. I know, in the real-world complexity analysis, we sometimes indulge in *technical hypocrisy* (like claiming Big-O (worst case scenario) of get from HashTable is Time-O(1), when it's actually O(N), but rare enough for us to claim it relevant, or insert into the end of Dynamic array is Time-O(1), when it's also O(N), but the Amortized analysis claims it's as well rare enough to claim it's Time-O(1)).

Is it one of these situations, when the insertion into static array is actually Space-O(N), but we take it for granted it's Space-O(1), or do I misunderstand, how space complexity works?

Comment: "*I thought we look at 'the difference in memory after the completion of the run of the algorithm*" no, it's **during** the algorithm's run. Otherwise almost any algorithm would have `O(1)` space complexity as the extra space used while they run is usually freed up.  However, it's more important to know how much space they consume at most, rather than after the fact.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Does that mean insert into static array is SO(N), as it needs to copy the array? And does that mean the general approach to defining Space complexity is alike Time complexity in the sense if one operation is O(X), the entire algorithm is MINIMUM O(X) ?

Comment: Inserting into an array by copying into a new one and freeing the old one takes O(N) space.  Also hash table insert is O(N) for most implementations, and saying it's O(1) is not hypocrisy, it's sloppiness -- failing to say the word "expected".  Similarly inserting into a dynamic array is O(N), but O(1) amortized.  The source that you're learning these things from doesn't appear to be very accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Space complexity simply describes how memory consumption is related to the size of input data.

In case of SO(1), the memory consumption of a program does not depend on the size of input. Example of this would be "grep", "sed" and similar tools that operate on streams. For a bigger dataset they would simply run more time. In Java for example you have SAX XML Parser which does not build DOM model in memory, but emits events for XML elements as it sees them; thus it can work with very large XML documents even on machines with limited memory.

In case of SO(N), memory consumption of a program grows linearly with the size of input. So if a program consumes 500 MB for 200 records and 700 MB for 400 records, then you know it will consume 1 GB for 700 records. Most programs actually fall in this category. For example, an email that is twice as long as some other email will consume twice as much space.

Programs that consume beyond SO(N) usually deal with complex data analysis, such as machine learning, AI, or data science. There you want to study relationships between individual records, so you sometimes build higher dimensional "cubes" and you get SO(N^2), SO(N^3) etc.

So technically it's not correct to say that "insertion into a static array is SO(N)". The correct thing to say would be that "an algorithm for XYZ has space complexity SO(N)".

Time and space complexity are important when you are sizing your infrastructure. For example, you have tested your system on 50 users, but you know that in production there will be 10000 users, so you ask yourself "how much RAM, disk and CPU do I need to have in my server".

In many cases, time and space can be traded for each other. There's no better way to see this than in databases. For example, a table can have indexes which consume some additional space, but give you a huge speedup for looking up things because you don't have to search through all the records.

Another example of trading time for space would be cracking password hashes using rainbow tables. There you are essentially pre-computing some data which later saves you a lot of work, as you don't have to perform those expensive computations during cracking, but only look up the already calculated result.

Comment: good examples, thank you for them. Please, let me rephrase my initial question - is algorithm for inserting into static array, which has to copy the entire array, add the insertee and then clear space of old array - SO(N)?

Comment: Yes, such an algorithm would need to hold N*2 + 1 entries in memory at its peak, so it's SO(2*N + 1) = SO(N).

Comment: So, on the topic of the claim of this algorithm being SO(1) - is it somewhat reasonable to say, by the same principle of saying Get from HashTable is Time-O(1)?

Comment: Time complexity of "get" from hashtable depends on the hashing function that is being used. With a perfect hashing function, get is indeed O(1), but in this case the hash table really behaves like an array. On the other extreme, with a completely useless hashing function the hashtable effectively behaves like a list with O(N) for get. Since perfect hash functions are hard to find, most real-world cases are somewhere in between :-)

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, technically the "get" is O(N) (Big-O = worst case scenario -> hash table becomes an array with 1 element - linked list, containing all elements, we need to get the last one in this list, which is O(N), where N is the amount of Items in the hash table). But we still use O(1) as the complexity of a general hashTable's "get". By the same principle, is it reasonable to suggest insert into static array being Space-O(1), when in reality it is Space-O(N), or is it, unlike the hashTable situation, completely unreasonable?

Comment: I don't seem to understand your question. What exactly does the operation "insert into static array" do? Does it need to allocate a new array and copy the old data over? In that case it needs SO(N + 1). If the space is preallocated, it needs SO(0). But this is realy just saying the same thing twice, like 1 == 1.

Comment: I see. My general question is - having an algorithm that allocates N+1 slots for new array, copies the old one and adds the new element, is there ANY ground to claim its SO(1), using the same principle we claim "add to the end of dynamic array" is Time-O(1)?

Comment: As long as the space allocated by an algorithm is linearly proportional to the size of data, that means SO(N) and not SO(1). Like I said, SO(N) is just a synonim for saying the same thing. But if you want, you can always find a contrived example for which you can argue differently (e.g. copy-on-write allocations). So when talking about SO(x) it's essential that you define the scope, understand what is really happening, and make it clear what you are refering to (physical memory, virtual memory, do you count shared memory twice etc.) SO(x) is a blunt tool that cannot explain all the details.